# Give a basis for $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt 3\right)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. What is the dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given the formula:

suppose for a field $F$ and some $\alpha$, we define: $F(\alpha) = \lbrace c_0 + c_1\alpha + c_2\alpha^2 + c_3\alpha^3 + \cdots \vert c_i\in F\rbrace$

${c_0+c_1\sqrt{3}+c_2\sqrt{3}^2+c_3\sqrt{3}^3+c_4\sqrt{3}^4 + \cdots}$

every even term comes out as a constant and every odd term comes out$\sqrt{3}^{2k+1}$

which means the basis is along the lines of ${1,\sqrt{3}^{2k+1}}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$  with dimension of 2

Comment: Simpler to just write $1,\sqrt 3$ as a basis (your family of bases is really just the same as this...all you do is to multiply the second term by some integer power of $3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot that 
$\;\bigl(\sqrt 3\bigr)^{2k+1}=\bigl(\sqrt 3\bigr)^{2k}\sqrt 3=3^k\sqrt 3$.

More generally, it is very simple to prove that if $\alpha$ is any element algebraic over a field $F$, with minimal polynomial of degree $d$, the $F$-algebra $F[\alpha]$  is generated, as an $F$-vector space by $\; 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots, \alpha^{d-1}$ (which are a basis).

*Here is an outline*:

Let $P_\min(X)$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. A typical  element of $F[\alpha]$ is just a polynomial $P(X)$ evaluated at  $\alpha$.

Now, it $\deg P(X)<d$, there's nothing to prove. If $\deg P(X)\ge d$, the Euclidean division by $P_\min(X)$ yields  a quotient $Q(X)$ and a remainder $R(x)$ such that
$$P(X)=Q(X)P_\min(X)+R(X)\qquad(\deg R(X)<d)$$
whence
$$P(\alpha)=Q'\alpha)P_\min(\alpha)+R(\alpha)=R(\alpha)$$
which proves the set $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots, \alpha^{d-1}\}$ is a set of generators. Furthermore this set is linearly independent because of the minimality of the degree of $P_\min$.

Answer (score 4):

The observation that $\{ \sqrt{3}^k ~|~ k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ forms a spanning set is a good one, and your idea to case on $k$ being even or odd to try to simplify this spanning set down to a basis is *also* a good idea!

What you want to think about now is which powers we *need* to use. As you've noticed, we don't need any even powers except $k=0$, because whenever we have $\sqrt{3}^{2k}$, we can always rewrite it as $(\sqrt{3}^2)^k = 3^k$, which is already a multiple of $1 = \sqrt{3}^0$.

The next observation is for *odd* powers, we can run the same argument! $\sqrt{3}^{2k+1} = \sqrt{3}^{2k} * \sqrt{3} = 3^k * \sqrt{3}$, which is a multiple of $\sqrt{3}$!

So, by taking $\{1, \sqrt{3} \}$ as a spanning set, we can actually get *any* sum of powers of $\sqrt{3}$. Thus, $\{1, \sqrt{3}\}$ is still spanning... but is it a basis?

The answer is, of course, yes! Let's write $a1 + b\sqrt{3} = 0$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Can you show that $a$ and $b$ must both be $0$? Thus showing $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$ is linearly independent?

**Edit:**

And since you have a basis of size $2$, this of course means that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is a vector-space of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I believe the set is linearly dependent

Comment: Great! Can you _prove_ it, though?

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-3)$.

$x^2-3$ is irreducible, and $\{1,\sqrt3\}$ is a basis, since $\sqrt3$ is a root.